# Bubbling browserTrigger() event

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use [browserTrigger()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngScenario/browserTrigger.js) on an element and need the event on to bubble up to its ancestors, but the handler from the element (ancestor) isn't firing

This is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<div ng-click="catchMe()">
  <span>ClickMe</span>
</div>
```

And from the spec:

```
var child = $document.find('span');
browserTrigger(child,'click');
```

The `catchMe()` event (div's click handler) isn't getting fired.

I checked the code from [browserTrigger](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngScenario/browserTrigger.js#L127) and the event that is pass to `element.dispatchEvent(env)` is with `canBubble : true`, so I don't get why it isn't bubbling

**Update:**

I did a simple working bubbling [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dimirc/fApb6/)

But if I run it as a test, the bubbling isn't happening:

```
it('should bubble event to parent element', function () {

  $scope.total = 0;
  var template = '<div class="out" ng-click="total = total + 1"><div class="in"></div></div>';
  var el = $compile(template)($scope);

  var divOut = el[0];
  browserTrigger(divOut,'click');
  expect($scope.total).toBe(1);

  var divIn = el[0].children[0];
  browserTrigger(divIn,'click');
  expect($scope.total).toBe(2);  // < ------ FAIL: $scope.total = 1

});
```

Comment: `<div ng-click="catchMe">` to `<div ng-click="catchMe()">`

Comment: @JonathandeM. thanks, was a typo on the example but the problem isn't that, since if I click directly the div form browser I get the expected behavior. Should be something related to dispatchEvent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit test angular right-click directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720009/unit-test-angular-right-click-directive)

Answer (score 0):

BrowserTrigger() is deprecated. 
Use:

`element.triggerHandler("click");`